# Ошибка отсутствия класса контроллера

Tags: php, laravel

В чём ошибка?

//Error

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [app/Http/Controllers/TestController] does not exist.
```

//Rout

```
Route::get('/test/show/', 'TestController@show');
```

//TestControllers.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    
    class TestController extends Controller
    {
        public function show()
        {
            return 'TestController';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы провайдер роутов не меняли?

Comment: Просто он у вас ищет app\Http\Controllers\TestController а неймспейс контроллера App\Http\Controllers

Comment: Проблема остаётся, смена пути не помогла

Comment: Причём тут путь? Он у вас ищет app\Http\Controllers а должен App\Http\Controllers посмотрите какой дефолтный неймспейс у роутов в провайдере

Comment: И почему он у вас юзает контроллер который находиться в том же неймспейсе?

Comment: Как таковой это ошибки не даст, но есть вероятность что вы создали контроллер в другую папку, и после этого перенесли его в корневую папку контроллеров, но при этом не изменили неймспейс контроллера

Comment: И если он у вас лежит в другой папке и неймспейс у него правильный то и объявлять роут надо `Route::get('/test/show/', 'addingNameSpace\TestController@show'')` А ещё лучше через юзы если у вас более свежая лара `Route::get('/test/show', [TestController::class, 'show'])` и заюзать сам класс контроллера

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Решил ситуацию добавлением в web.php записи 'use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;'